# Force image tag to be perfect circle

Tags: html, css

Is this possible? I want an image to be a perfect circle no matter if the image is not a perfect square ie: `100px x 100px`.

```
.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

With that code, if the image is 200x150, the `img` tag would be in the shape of an oval. Could I get a perfect circle no matter the image size?

```
<img class="circle" src="/link/to/img.jpg" height="80" width="80" />
```

Comment: @Paulie_D How is that? JS involved? I must get the perfect circle no matter what. Stupid, I know.

Comment: No, see my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you need to wrap the image in a div, apply the rounding to that and hide any overflow.

Here I have also centered the image with flexbox but that's not a requirement.

```css
.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
</div>

<h2> Actual Image</h2>

  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
```

Comment: Yep. Perfect. Thanks. Can mark this the answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old but there is actually a way to achieve what is asked without using a wrapper div:

```
.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

<img class="circle" src="/link/to/img.jpg" height="80" width="80" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property.
It won't matter if the image is wide or long, it'll always be laid out in a perfect circle.

```
.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: center;
```

```
<img class="circle" src="/link/to/img.jpg" height="80" width="80" />
```

Here's the example using all different size images:
https://codepen.io/rockycorp/pen/ZEKbzzp